# how can I use onActivityResult()?

Tags: android

I want to select photo from gallery put it in imageView then select applications from a list of installed application, finally when I click on button "Finish" I insert the selected list of app and photo in my data base. All that should be in the same activity

So my activity contains:
-ImageView
-Button "Select Application"
-Button "Finish"

Now when I click on "Finish" just the photo is inserted in my ImageView but I can't retrieve list of package Name, So how can I use onActivityResult() to solve this pb?

Comment: show some code. also the question is unclear. did you implement your own activity chooser?

Answer (score 0):

From the `Intent` you used to start image picker

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
for(ResolveInfo info : getPackageManager()
        .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onActivityResult()`  is called only if `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);`

And in `onActivityResult` you should check `requestcode` for its response.